# REST webServices for android

Tags: android, web-services

First of all, sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm new with android and I'm just learning about webservices.

I have to develop an app that creates a simple user login interface, where you can create, update, delete and list the introduced users. This using a REST web service.

Have to say that I have the app finished and running, but with a webservice that it has been given to me to develop this app.

Now I have to do the same, but using other REST webService that I can find around. But I have no idea about this.

I've tried searching about this but still haven't got clear enough on how to do it.

Is there any free webservice that I can use for this?

Comment: There is no need to be apologetic @masmic_87. Not everyone can know everything, right?

Comment: @hiphopdroid your right ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are [a lot of weather services](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2009/04/15/5-weather-apis-from-weatherbug-to-weather-channel/), which have a public rest service for free. Also the [Federal Aviation Administration](https://services.faa.gov/) provides some APIs about airports and flights.

Comment: But what I need is to make some kind of create user, list created users, delete user, etc.. can I do this with those weather services